# Does thermionic emission require vacuum?

Tags: electricity, electrons, vacuum

Every source I looked at talks about thermionic emission within the context of vacuum tubes. However I was wondering if vacuum is a requirement for this effect to work. Can any cathode, if sufficiently heated, emit electrons?

Comment: Yes, they just won't go very far until they run into stuff. And the hot cathode isn't going to like having air around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vacuum is not a requirement, except for specific applications such as the Edison effect. The original discovery was not in a vacuum. You can read about it in 
[this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermionic_emission)